# What is the fastest way to get a MethodBase object?

Tags: .net, performance, reflection

I have a Type object, and a method name:

```
Type type;  
string methodName;
```

And i need a MethodBase object for the method "methodName", somewhere in the stack.
This works:

```
MethodBase nemo;
StackTrace st = new StackTrace(); // Behaves poorly...
for(int i =0; i< st.FrameCount; i++ )
{
   StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(i);
   if (sf.GetMethod().Name == methodName)
   {
       nemo = sf.GetMethod();      
   }
}
```

But i need a faster approach...

Comment: have you found a better way meantime? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write  `type.GetMethod(methodName)`.

Comment: He apparently wants an instance of that method as it appears in the call stack, not a new one that isn't currently executing.

Comment: @Keith: Methods don't have instances.  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @KeithS - Reflection metadata doesn't look any different whether you get it from the callstack, or from the type. Walking the callstack is only necessary if you don't know *which siganture of the method may appear* - in which case, it's unavoidable.

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks, but it is not the same - it does not work for constructors... type.GetMethod(".ctor") returns null. StackFrame.GetMethod worked for every method.

Comment: @seldary: Then call `.GetConstructors()`.

Comment: @SLaks: I too can read msdn... and even if use it i don't know which ctor was called.
and there are other problems aside from ctors.
i need a WORKING solution (exactly as the StackFrame solution), and a FAST one at the same time.